# How can i perform a simple 'fade out then fade in' with Page Route Builder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I am trying to achieve a nice simple fade animation from one navigation route to another using `PageRouteBuilder`. I want the current route to fade out completely, then after the old route is gone, the new route should fade in.

So far in my PageRouteBuilder class, I can fade the new route in from 0 to 1, but I want the old route to fade out fully first, then after the old route has faded out for the new route to fade in. So far in my current code, the old route disappears suddenly once the new route fading in has finished.

I also want to emphasise that I do not want them to fade out/in at the same time, but for the fade out of the old route then fade in for the new route to happen in sequence.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FadePageTransition extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget child;

  FadePageTransition({
    required this.child,
  }) : super(
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => child,
        );

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) => FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: child,
      );
}
```

I know that the `secondaryAnimation` property controls the animation for how the old route leaves, doesn't it? but i'm just not sure how that would work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 `FadeTransition` in `transitionBuilder:` is the solution to your problem.

If that explanation is kinda hard to understand, this is how you use it.

```
transitionsBuilder: (
       BuildContext context,
       Animation<double> animation,
       Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
       Widget child,
   ) {
     return FadeTransition(
       opacity: animation,
       child: FadeTransition(
         opacity: secondaryAnimation,
         child: child,
       ),
     );
   }
```

That's it!

Comment: I placed the return statement into the buildTransitions of my class and it didn't work unfortunately. It just gives me a blank screen and doesn't go to the next route at all.

Comment: I wrote this without testing it, sorry. But basically, secondaryAnimation is the property controls the animation for how the old route leaves, modify it and then you can have your result. So, can you fix the code for me please, it's 5 am here and my phone isn't around.

Comment: @TrầnTrungHiếu danny471 was close. I've added the solution.

Comment: this solution does not work, isn't there any solution simplier than MetaStack's ? It feels like it should be possible to use existing Fade transitions instead of custom ones

Answer (score 0):

You have to make special curves to get this to work.

```
class DelayedCurve extends Curve {
  const DelayedCurve() : super();

  @override
  double transformInternal(double t) {
    if (t < 0.5) {
      return 0.0;
    } else {
      return (t - 0.5) * 2.0;
    }
  }
}

class CurveDelayed extends Curve {
  const CurveDelayed() : super();

  @override
  double transformInternal(double t) {
    if (t > 0.5) {
      return 1.0;
    } else {
      return t * 2;
    }
  }
}
```

and you have to drive them correctly.

```
class FadeFirstTransition extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget child;

  FadeFirstTransition({
    required this.child,
  }) : super(
          transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
          reverseTransitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 3000),
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => child,
        );

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation, Widget child) =>
      FadeTransition(
          opacity: animation.drive(Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
              .chain(CurveTween(curve: const DelayedCurve()))),
          child: FadeTransition(
            opacity: secondaryAnimation.drive(Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0)
                .chain(CurveTween(curve: const CurveDelayed()))),
            child: child,
          ));
}
```